# Fix position of legend in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure

How do I fix the position of a legend in a MATLAB figure?

I'm currently building a GUI, intended for public use, and when figures inside the GUI are produced I do not want the user to be able to move the legend by click-and-drag. Anyone?

Comment: couldnt find anything about that: there is no callback for the legend, other stuff like dynamiclegend doesnt work either, as far as i see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the buttonDownFcn from the legend.

snippet:

```
line(rand(1,3),rand(1,3))
l=legend('location','ne')
set(l,'ButtonDownFcn',[])
```

Comment: just nice, didnt know there was a callback!